# Copystored array value into arraylist JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, int

I have a int array with 2 number.
I wan to copy this number into array list and print them out.
as much as possible refrain from using Integer result[];

```
  int result[] = {1024,2048};
  List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>(result);


public class TEA {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

          int result[] = {1024,2048};
          List<int[]> res = Arrays.asList(result);
          System.out.println(res);


    }

}
```

> output :[[I@3312b1dd]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't make `result` into an `Integer[]` instead of an `int[]`, your options are either to do an explicit `for` loop:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int value : array) {
  list.add(value);
}
```

...or, if you can use third-party libraries, use Guava's [`Ints.asList(int[])`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList%28int...%29).  That's more or less the entire space of your options.

Comment: this is to add in new value,so it is not possible to copy existing array without using Integer result[]?

Comment: ...I'm not sure what you're saying.  These are essentially the only options if you want to get an `int[]` to a `List<Integer>`, but it's not clear what you mean by "this is to add in new value."

Answer (score 0):

Use [Arrays.asList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) method to do the same.

```
List<Integer> res = Arrays.asList(result);
```

This is a list view of the array, you can't add or delete elements.

```
List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(result));
```

Copies all elements from the source array into a new list.

**EDITED:**

There is no automatic conversion from array of primitive type to array of their wrapper reference types.

```
int result[] = {1024,2048};
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int value : result) {
    list.add(value);
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: not working for both...i getting error, i also tired changing integer to int[], it return some rubbish value

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<int[]> to List<Integer>

 at TEA.main(TEA.java:74)